# Java 9 install not being seen by eclipse

Tags: windows-10, java, eclipse

I'm trying to install the java 9 jdk. I have followed the installer from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html three times now. When I complete the install I have a jdk and jre folder, but when I bring it into eclipse oxygen and select either the jdk or jre folder it says there is no jre. I copied the javaw.exe file from the jdk to my eclipse configuration settings folder, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Check out the Eclipse and Java 9 wiki page - https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

Answer (score 0):

The original release of Eclipse Oxygen did not contain Java 9 support unless you installed a patch. You need Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) for full Java 9 support.